# Declare session with express node.js and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm doing an application with Node.js, Express, MongoDB (mongoose), I'm trying to make the database connection in a separate file from `server.js`, but I'm having a hard time with connect-mongo.

First in my server.js I had this:

```
/* jshint esversion: 6 */
'use strict';
let express = require('express');

const db = require('./app/config/db');
const routes = require('./app/routes/routes');
const users = require('./app/routes/users');

let app = express();

const conn = db.connect();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

...

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

app.listen(3000);

module.exports = app;
```

This only handle the application routes, and the application server, then I had the next folder structure for my project:

```
myApp
|___app
    |___bin
    |___config
        |___credentials.js
        |___db.js
    |___controllers
    |___routes
    |___views
|___node_modules
|___package.json
|___server.js
```

Welll insidde config folder I had two javascripts that handle the connection to the database, in the credentials.js literally only had the credentials for the access of the database.

Then my problem is inside the db.js, next I show you the file:

```
/* jshint esversion: 6 */
'use strict';
let mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    async = require('async'),
    express = require('express');

const credentials = require('./credentials');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

let db = mongoose.connection,
    app = express();

exports.connect = function(done){
   const connection = mongoose.connect(credentials.host, credentials.database, credentials.port, credentials.db);

   db.on('error', (error =>{
       console.log("Error estableciendo la conexion");
       process.exit(1);
   }));

   db.on('open', (argv)=>{
       db.db.listCollections().toArray((err, collections)=>{
           collections.forEach(x => console.log(x));
       });
   });

   /* Define sessions in MongoDB */
   app.use(session({
       secret: credentials.sessionSecret,
       store: new MongoStore({ dbPromise: db })
   }));
}
```

I got the next error:
[Error with nodemon server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAeNr.png)

Do you know how to initiate connect-mongo using this project structure?

By the way, in the credentials.js file I setup Bluebird as my promise library.

In advance thank you!

Comment: is db.on('open'...) getting called?

Comment: @MananVaghasiya Hello. Yes I actually had a console.log inside that tells me if the connection is established, so I really don't know whats the problem.

Comment: the problem is definitely "db" not being promise. Are you sure mongoose.connection is a promise?

Comment: @MananVaghasiya you were right this has being an issue with the new express version, I change the approach to a simple connection. with `mongoose.connection(uri)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, like @MananVaghasiya said, that my variable `db` was not a Promise, this is a bug inside the mongoose project, so I changed the connection type to a basic uri connection with mongoose and then after the query of login I set the session.

The code it's looking like this at this time, so thank you for your time.

```
module.exports.login = (req, res)=>{
    const mail = req.body.mail.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, ''),
          password = req.body.password;

    user.findOne({$and:[{'mail' : mail}, {'password': password}]}, (err, user)=>{
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            /* Define sessions in MongoDB */
           app.use(session({
               secret: credentials.sessionSecret,
               store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: db }),
               saveUnitialized: true,
               resave: false,
               cookie:{
                   path: "/"
               },
               name: user.role
           }));
           return user;
       }
   });
};
```